# Разница между import и from import

Tags: python, python-3.x

Подскажите в чем заключается разница между

```
import x
```

и

```
from x import *
```

Если это важно, то интересует конкретно flask.

Просто у меня в одном месте кода используется второй вариант, а в другом его использование дает ошибку, но работает первый. Никак не пойму в каком случае надо использовать каждый из них.

Comment: В первом случае вам нужно указывать имя модуля перед перед именем функций и переменных из этого модуля.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Разница в пространстве имен (namespace).

При импортировании:

```
import module_name
```

все переменные и функции модуля `module_name` будут зарегистрированы с префиксом импортируемого модуля, т.е. для доступа к ним надо будет использовать имя модуля в качестве префикса:

```
module_name.function_name(...)
```

часто используется `alias` для сокращения имени, например:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# при использовании пользуются алиасом вместо полного имени модуля:
data = np.random.randint(100, size=(10,10))
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

При импортировании:

```
from module_name import *
```

все переменные и функции будут зарегистрированы в глобальном пространстве имен как есть без префикса:

```
function_name(...)
```

**ВНИМАНИЕ**: данный вариант более опасен, т.к. в том случае если в вашем глобальном пространстве имен уже существуют переменные / функции с таким именем - они будут переписаны новыми импортируемыми!

Пример (**не надо так делать**):

```
In [37]: from random import random

In [38]: random()
Out[38]: 0.8038272255488926

In [39]: from numpy import random

In [40]: random()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-40-347a394b3b57> in <module>()
----> 1 random()

TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

Comment: Я понял Ваш ответ. Спасибо! Но тогда возникает другой вопрос. Допустим у меня есть файл, который называется name. Мне нужно в определенном месте другого файла (допустим, main), выполнить целиком код из файла name, как если бы его содержимое просто было написано в main. Если написать в main "import name" - это работает. А если написать "from name import *" - не работает. Это нормально? И может быть я вообще делаю эту задачу неправильно и есть другие способы?

Comment: @КонстантинКомиссаров, это зависит от того как выглядит ваш `name` скрипт. Обычно импортируют функции, переменные и классы. Обрамите код из файла `name` в функцию (класс) и вызывайте данную функцию в основном скрипте (после импорта)